# IF scroll up - call function

Tags: javascript

I wanna call my_function1 when user scroll up (in the full-screen height page) or call my_function2 when the user scrolls down.

When I open a page with this code, it will always immediately run function in else {} (in this code example "slide_down();". What am I doing wrong, please?

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > position) {
    slide_up();
  } else {
    slide_down();
  }
  position = scroll;
});
```

Comment: Well, at page load `scroll` and `position` probably have the same values, so `scroll > position` is `false`.

Comment: Swap `slide_up()` and `slide_down()`. Other than that your code should work kinda correct. If it doesn't, theres more code you are not showing us

Comment: `} else if(scroll < position) {` might help

Comment: @FelixKling The code is inside $(window).scroll(... so it shouldn't do anything on pageload.

Comment: @Xatenev:  I believe browsers trigger a scroll event on page load. Maybe only when the document is larger than the viewport.

Comment: @FelixKling Dunno, just tried it in jsfiddle and it didn't but it might be that jsfiddle suppresses this event.

Comment: @Xatenev: I read somewhere that the even might only be triggered on page reload if the browser remembered the previous scroll position. Since we don't know what the OP is doing we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Now I use this code:
`// Scroll function
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > position) {
    console.log("Down");
  } else {
    console.log("Up");
  }
  position = scroll;
});`

Console shows once "Up" after page load. "Down" never triggered. Scrolling is not detected or something, "Up" is in console only on page load.

Comment: Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t4ke8p5g8lglm4/Screenshot%202018-06-05%2021.34.09.png?dl=0

Comment: @FelixKling Ah yeah then it makes a lot of sense, right, browsers refresh scroll position usually. Ty for the clear-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working in my scenario (detecting mouse wheel in full-screen page)

```
  // Detect IE version
var iev=0;
var ieold = (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent));
var trident = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/);
var rv=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0");

if (ieold) iev=new Number(RegExp.$1);
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") != -1) iev=10;
if (trident&&rv!=-1) iev=11;

// Firefox or IE 11
if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined' || iev == 11) {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(st < lastScrollTop) {
            console.log('Up');
        }
        else if(st > lastScrollTop) {
            console.log('Down');
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
}
// Other browsers
else {
    $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            console.log('Up');
        }
        else if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            console.log('Down');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that detects if the user has scrolled up or down and is mobile friendly too.

`console.log()` is acting up in code snippets as the log is called for every pixel scrolled.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
// element should be replaced with the actual target element on which you have applied scroll, use window in case of no target element.

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
   
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      // Do scroll down code
      console.log("Down");
   } else {
      // Do scroll up code
      console.log("Up");
   }
   
   lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
   
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied all this code and it shows nothing in my console :/

Comment: Did you copy to test it or did you change everything?

Comment: I see the problem now. When I tried to scroll on the long page, this code works well. But I need use this on page with only 100% window height to run functions when someone scroll.

Comment: So you need it on a div then?

Comment: Its like full-screen slider page. But custom. I've created nice transitions and custom animations when someone clicks on the "scroll down" button. But I need run same actions when someone uses the mouse wheel for the scroll.

Comment: In the above code, I explained that I used `window.addEventListener()` to listen to all interactions happening in the `window` object. That object can be anything.
Example: `let div  = getDocumentById("divID"); div.addEventListener('scroll', { /*[Your Code Here]*/ });` and then you can use `this` keyword. Instead of `console.log()` you can write your code. Example: `this.className = "customTransition"`

Comment: Or just use `jQuery` and don't re-invent the wheel, just modify it instead.

Comment: this gives me error `let div = getDocumentById("divID");
div.addEventListener('scroll', {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > position) {
    console.log("Down");
  } else if (scroll < position) {
    console.log("Up");
  }
  position = scroll;
});
`